# Find shared libraries that ldd won't list?

Tags: linux, dependencies, shared-library

I have a script that would run through and pull in needed shared libraries (and another that will report unused libraries), using `ldd` however certain things like the `libnss_*` items part of the `glibc` don't show up.  How can I find those type of dependencies?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: you can't.

Loading a library can be done at program initialization with hard-coded library names, and that's what ldd detects.

However, any program can also at runtime load symbols from any library, and the name of that library can be computed at run-time as well; the most obvious use case for that is plugin systems!

You hence can't know that without running the program in exactly the use case that makes it load that library (e.g., if you have say an image editor, that could decide to load a library for loading jpeg files no earlier than you actually trying to open a jpeg file).

Since knowing all libraries loaded at run time is an impossible problem, package scripts, like the
.spec files needed to build rpm packages for redhat/fedora, need packagers to manually specify those dependencies that cannot be auto-detected.